# making an ajax call in jquery

Tags: jquery, json, ajax

I am trying to pass the following data to my action using ajax call.  I am not sure what I am doing wrong but the client id is always 0.  I am hard coding the client id in the call, but I still see zero.  Everything else is getting passed correctly.

```
 data: {
     "BedID": bedID, 
     "BedNumber": bedNumber,
     "ClientSearchItem": { 
         "ClientID": 160 
     },
     "BuildingName": buildingName,
     "RoomName": roomName,
     "RoomNumber": roomNumber, 
     "SiteName": siteName
},
```

// my ajax call

```
$.ajax({
        url: myUrl
        type: "GET",
        dataType: "JSON",
        data: {
            "BedID": bedID, "BedNumber": bedNumber, "ClientSearchItem": { "ClientID": 160 }, "BuildingName": buildingName,
            "RoomName": roomName, "RoomNumber": roomNumber, "SiteName": siteName
        },
        success: function (data) {
            // do something here
        },
        error: function (error) {
            alert("An error occured");
        }
    });

 public class SearchClient
    {
        // parameterless constructor
        public SearchClient()
        {

        }
        public int BedID { get; set; }
        public int BedNumber { get; set; }
        public string BuildingName { get; set;}
        //public int ClientID { get; set; }
        public ClientSearchItem ClientSearchItem { get; set; }
        public bool IsReservation { get; set;}
        public string RoomName { get; set;}
        public string RoomNumber { get; set; }
        public string BedManageOption { get; set; }

        public string SiteName { get; set;}
        [Required]
        public string StartDate { get; set;}
        public string StartTime { get; set;}
        public DateTimePicker EndDateTime { get; set;}
        public string Url { get; set; }
    }

public ActionResult _AddClientToBed(SearchClient model)
        {
         // do something here
}
```

Comment: Can you post your ajax call please?

Comment: @See Dart - I have updated my post.

Comment: Could it be because you're nesting it? What you've given us isn't a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) question. Thus, making it hard for us to help you.

Comment: Yes, ClientSearchItem is a nested object.  One of its properties is ClientID.  I am not sure how to pass that correctly.  All the other parameters are getting passed correctly to the action method I have show above.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would suggest couple of points in order to make your code working.

1) First add contentType: "application/json".

2) Second, make Ajax request as "POST" request so that Asp.Net MVC can easily resolve the form content into complex object. (Though it should resolve the complex object from query string as well). 
3) Stringify your input data.

Your ajax call would look like below.

```
        $.ajax({
            url: myUrl,
            type: "POST",
            data: JSON.stringify({
                   "BedID": bedID, "BedNumber": bedNumber, "ClientSearchItem": { "ClientID": 160 }, "BuildingName": buildingName,
                   "RoomName": roomName, "RoomNumber": roomNumber, "SiteName": siteName
            }),
            contentType: "application/json",
            success: function (data) {
                // do something here
            },
            error: function (error) {
                alert("An error occured");
            }
        })
```

Try it once and confirm it worked for you.

Comment: I tried your solution, but it did not work.  With this solution, all the properties are getting either null or 0 when I inspect the model.

Comment: It actually works.  I commented data: and replaced it with contentType: and used HttpGet as you suggested.  Thank you very much.  I am wondering why HttpGet doesnt work.  What I am doing is really a GET.

Comment: Are you sure ajax is passing correct data to application ? I mean did you check with fiddler or other network intercepting tool to see if values are correctly been passed to method. Because it's working perfectly in my application. I decorated my action method with HttpPost to accept Post request only. You may share your action method as well in order to take a look into that as well.

Comment: Glad to hear code worked for you. Happy Programming!!